# Configure routing so LAN connections go through wifi and WAN through modem

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, xubuntu

I have to configure my machine, so that packets for local machines (in the 192.168.*.* subnet)  go through my wireless network, and WAN connections (any other IP address), go through modem.

Consider following example:

I open a web browser and type `192.168.1.4/my_intranet_website`. I want to make sure that all traffic regarding this request goes through my wireless LAN interface.  But when I type `www.superuser.com` (which is outside of my local network) I want this traffic to go through my USB modem.

I tried to figure out, which `/dev` entries stand for which network interfaces, but I cannot do even that. I remember, then when I used Debian, it was `/dev/wan0` or `/dev/eth0` for wireless/wired and `/dev/wcdma0` for the USB modem. Here? No idea. The modem is an USB modem, so I think it may be one of `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

Really sorry for such a laconic description of the problem, but that is how noob I am :/ I will provide any further necessary information.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: traceroute output:

1. When both (modem and wlan) connections are up:

   ```
   sopel@mediacenter:/dev$ traceroute www.superuser.com
   traceroute to www.superuser.com (151.101.129.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets    
   1  netiaspot.home (192.168.1.254)  2.904 ms  4.580 ms  6.440 ms
   2  83.238.252.80 (83.238.252.80)  28.329 ms  28.679 ms  30.332 ms
   3  83.238.113.24 (83.238.113.24)  41.348 ms  41.340 ms  41.310 ms
   4  83.238.252.62 (83.238.252.62)  42.953 ms  43.643 ms  43.633 ms
   5  83.238.248.183 (83.238.248.183)  47.110 ms  47.112 ms  48.809 ms
   6  149.6.28.97 (149.6.28.97)  54.555 ms  34.576 ms  38.036 ms
   7  130.117.3.29 (130.117.3.29)  44.751 ms  46.638 ms  48.214 ms
   8  154.54.38.205 (154.54.38.205)  55.980 ms  65.842 ms  69.702 ms
   9  * * *
   ...
   30  * * *


   sopel@mediacenter:/dev$ traceroute 192.168.1.1
   traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   1  * * *
   2  * * *
   3  * * *
   ...
   30  * * *
   ```
2. When only the modem is up

   ```
   sopel@mediacenter:/dev$ traceroute www.superuser.com
   traceroute to www.superuser.com (151.101.129.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
    1  * * *
    2  * * *
    3  * * *
    4  * * *
    5  * * *
    6  185.89.184.2 (185.89.184.2)  104.232 ms  71.514 ms  82.738 ms
    7  * * *
    8  * * *
    9  * * *
   ...
   30  * * *

   sopel@mediacenter:/dev$ traceroute 192.168.1.1
   traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
    1  * * *
    2  * * *
    3  * * *
    4  * * *
    5  * * *
    6  * * *
    7  * * *
    8  * * *
   ...
   30  * * *
   ```

Please note that in second case 192.168.1.1 was unreachable (no LAN at all).

Comment: " so every package intended to be delivered to some LAN machine (IP starts with 192.168..) goes through my wireless network, and WAN connections (any other IP), go through modem." - What you want is not clear, what you describe is literally every network with a router connected to a modem, it isn't clear how your current setup doesn't meet these requirements.  You should edit your question to make that part clear.

Comment: OK, I will try to clarify this....

And done.

Comment: @Pawel Try running `traceroute 192.168.1.4` and `traceroute superuser.com` to see the route your packets take when headed to a LAN or WAN destination. Does it match what you expect? (If not, posting the output could be useful to answerers.)

Comment: I have appended outputs to the question. This is far away from a desired situation. When modem and wlan are up, all traffic goes through wlan. To force modem to be used, I have to turn wlan off.

Comment: OK, i tried, tried, and managed to solve this just by running one command. Amazing :)

Comment: Output of `ip route show` (as root user) is probably more useful than the traceroute - consider editing to add that.

Comment: This is exactly what i did - i displayed routes and deleted one that routes 0.0.0.0/128 through wlan adapter.